What psychology is applicable to the advice: do not go to the same cafe every day
I have heard of this advice from older and wiser people on the TV. They told the younger people not to go to the same cafe or bar every day, and I was wondering why.
And I tried it once: it turned out the waiters and waitresses start to not treat you as very important. My feeling was: if they feel they have "locked you in", that you are going there everyday anyway, they don't need to pay special attention to you. However, if you only go there once every two or three days, they have more "incentive" to be nicer to you, so that you visit them more often.
What actual psychology is applicable in this situation?
